# Type hint a decorated function with Protocols

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy, python-typing

I have a decorator that is taking a function as argument and returns a function with the same signature. The first argument to this function must have a `foo` attribute, and the decorator performs some side-effect based on this value.

I'm trying to hint types for all this with a mix of `Protocol` and `ParamSpec` (I'm using Python 3.10), but apparently I'm doing it wrong. Below is a toy implementation that fails.

```py
import functools
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, Protocol, TypeVar


class HasFoo(Protocol):
    foo: int


P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")


def print_foo(
    f: Callable[Concatenate[HasFoo, P], T]
) -> Callable[Concatenate[HasFoo, P], T]:
    """This is my decorator.

    It prints `x.foo` where `x` is the first argument of the
    decorated function.
    """

    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(has_foo: HasFoo, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        print(has_foo.foo)
        return f(has_foo, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped


class ReallyHasFoo:
    """Some actual implementation of `HasFoo`."""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.foo = 0


@print_foo
def f(has_foo: ReallyHasFoo) -> None:
    pass
```

With this example, `mypy` complains as follows:

```
test.py:37: error: Argument 1 to "print_foo" has incompatible type "Callable[[ReallyHasFoo], None]"; expected "Callable[[HasFoo], None]"
test.py:37: note: This may be because "f" has arguments named: "has_foo"
```

Any idea how to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@SUTerliakov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72974011/9681081) which explains the problem but does not provide a solution, I've been able to find one.

The issue is here:

```py
def print_foo(
    f: Callable[Concatenate[HasFoo, P], T]
) -> Callable[Concatenate[HasFoo, P], T]:
```

This signature assumes `f` can take any parameter that has a `foo` attribute, which is not true. As pointed by @SUTerliakov, the body of `f` could be:

```py
assert isinstance(has_foo, ReallyHasFoo)
```

The solution is to use a `TypeVar` instead of `HasFoo` as shown below:

```py
HasFooSubtype = TypeVar("HasFooSubtype", bound=HasFoo)


def print_foo(
    f: Callable[Concatenate[HasFooSubtype, P], T]
) -> Callable[Concatenate[HasFooSubtype, P], T]:
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(
        has_foo: HasFooSubtype, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs
    ) -> T:
        print(has_foo.foo)
        return f(has_foo, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped
```

A bit clumsy but it does what it does and mypy does not complain anymore.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve is not really type safe. You make a decorator that should work with any function that accepts `HasFoo` argument and, maybe, smth else. Your `f` does not accept arbitrary `HasFoo`, and [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=11d683725dce4ab4c6c2d7d73ec4cd83) is example how it can fail:

```
import functools
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, Protocol, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")

class HasFoo(Protocol):
    foo: int

def print_foo(
    f: Callable[Concatenate[HasFoo, P], T]
) -> Callable[Concatenate[HasFoo, P], T]:

    class MyOddHasFoo:
        foo: int = 1
        
    f(MyOddHasFoo())

    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(has_foo: HasFoo, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        print(has_foo.foo)
        return f(has_foo, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped


class ReallyHasFoo:
    foo: int = 0

@print_foo  # E: Argument 1 to "print_foo" has incompatible type "Callable[[ReallyHasFoo], None]"; expected "Callable[[HasFoo], None]"
def f(has_foo: ReallyHasFoo) -> None:
    assert isinstance(has_foo, ReallyHasFoo)
```

Now `mypy` raises the same error as in your question and is 100% valid, because this fails at runtime with `AssertionError`.

This is variance issue. Functions are contravariant in argument types - it means that `Callable[[float], None]` is a subtype of (`<:`) `Callable[[int], None]`, for example, because any function taking `float` must be fine with `int` input (`float :> int`), and you can pass the former instead of the latter to any decorator. With protocol you're doing the opposite.